# How would I go about integrating the rails console as a user interface in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone-views

I working on an rails application that has the requirement of allowing the user(s) to have what is described ad freeform exploration of the backend database.  I'm using a lot of scopes in the application and have begun to create a fairly descent DSL.

What I was hoping to create a view / user interface that was pretty much an irb or rails console.  So that the user could go to town exploring the table view the DSL or ruby/rails methods (Users.all) .I would also like to put some safeguards around what commands/methods that could be used, but as an initial step it would be great to know if the concept of an IRB-like view is even possible. If you have any examples or websites that mirror what I'm looking for, I'd be interested in hearing about them or if you are aware of an approach/gem to achieve this that would be even better.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of open-source projects that do something similar:

https://github.com/jwo/ruby-fiddle-web

https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors